# Canvas game increase enemies spawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a game I am making: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html

What I want to be able to do is when I kill a certain amount of enemies it will level up. This part is working, however I also want the spawn amount to increase when you level up.

In my loop function:

```
function Loop()
{
if (isPlaying == true)
{
updateLevel(); //this updates the level but it calls it every frame which might be bad.
Player1.draw();
drawAllEnemies();
updateStats();
requestAnimFrame(Loop);
}
```

The update level function:

```
function updateLevel()
{

  if(Player1.enemiesKilled <3)
  {

   level = 1;



  }

  else if(Player1.enemiesKilled > 3 && Player1.enemiesKilled <= 9)
  {
   level = 2;


  }
   else if(Player1.enemiesKilled > 9 && Player1.enemiesKilled <=18)
  {
   level = 3;

  }
    else if(Player1.enemiesKilled > 18 && Player1.enemiesKilled <= 38)
  {
   level = 4;

  }
     else if(Player1.enemiesKilled > 38 && Player1.enemiesKilled <= 70)
  {
   level = 5;
   s
  }

  else if (Player1.enemiesKilled > 120)
  {
  level = 6;

  }



  if(level == 1)
  {
    spawnAmount = 1;



  }

  else if(level == 2)
  {
    spawnAmount = 2;



  }

  else if(level == 3)
  {
    spawnAmount = 3;


  }

   else if(level == 4)
  {
    spawnAmount = 4;

  }

   else if(level == 5)
  {
    spawnAmount = 5;

  }

   else if(level == 6)
  {
    spawnAmount = 6;

  }




}
```

spawn enemy function:

```
function spawnEnemy(number) //total enemies starts at 0 and every-time you add to array
{
  for (var x = 0; x < number; x++)
   {

     enemies[enemies.length] = new Enemy();

   }

}
```

My init:

```
function init()
{

spawnEnemy(spawnAmount);
drawMenu();
sndIntro.play();
document.addEventListener('click', mouseClicked ,false);

}
```

I tried adding:  spawnEnemy(spawnAmount); to after I change the spawn amount global var in the updateLevel function but as this gets called every frame it makes hundreds of enemies fly at me. How can I solve this problem?

If I try something like this hundreds of enemies are genrated, I assume because it gets called every frame:

```
if(level == 1)
  {
    spawnAmount = 1;
  spawnEnemy(spawnAmount);
}
```

Comment: post the code where you call spawnEnemy() plz

Comment: I call it in my init, What I tried doing was putting in the call to the spawnEnemy method after I set the spawnAmount when I level up, but that just gets called every frame as its in the loop. I can't figure a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to increase the spawn rate on each level, I'd suggest you start off with a `spawnRate` first. Let `spawnRate` represent the number of game updates in between enemy spawns. Every time an enemy spawns, decrement another variable (say `spawnRateCountdown`), until that variable reaches 0, Then spawn an enemy. Reset the variable back up to the `spawnRate`. Rinse and repeat.

```
spawnRate = 60; /* one enemy every 60 updates. */
spawnRateCountdown = spawnRate;
function updateLoop() {
    spawnRateCountdown--;
    if (spawnRateCountdown == 0) {
        spawnRateCountdown = spawnRate;
        spawnEnemy();
    }
}
```

After that, you can just update your `spawnRate` variable as you see fit.

Comment: Effectively a throttle for spawn rate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't create new enemies from time to time, but just shift the same enemy further away on its explosion (i.e. call `recycleEnemy` method). This single enemy is spawned only once: `spawnEnemy` function is called in `init` method only with argument `1`.

You should rework enemy spawning algorithm. Below is a pretty good sample, which increases enemy spawning rate:

1. Remove `number` argument from `spawnEnemy` function: spawn only one enemy
2. Change `Enemy.prototype.recycleEnemy` function to remove `this` from `enemies`. Be cautious: if you'll call this function inside a loop by `enemies`, you will need to decrease counter to make sure that you won't skip next enemy: `--i`
3. Add a `function getSpawnCooldown() { return 100 / spawnAmount; }` (100 is approximate constant, you can variate it to change initial spawning rate)
4. Add a variable `time` which means the number of effective `Loop` calls from the beginning, defaults to 0
5. Add a variable `lastSpawnTime`, set it to 0
6. Inside `if` block of `Loop` function, add lines:

   1. `++time`
   2. `if (time >= lastSpawnTime + getSpawnCooldown()) spawnEnemy();`
7. In `spawnEnemy` function, add a line: `lastSpawnTime += getSpawnCooldown()`

Generally, you should better structurize your code. At least, split it to several js files which are responsible for different parts of your application.

Comment: With number 2, how would I remove it from the enemies array? something like enemies.remove(this);

Comment: `enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(this), 1);`